# iOS 7 does not support admob?

Tags: admob, ios7

This is my code:

```
gAdView=[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.height-GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
gAdView.adUnitID = admobID;
gAdView.rootViewController=self;
gAdView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:gAdView];
[gAdView loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
```

It works very good in iOS 5 & iOS 6, but in iOS 7 it not show?
WHY?
ADMOB LIB:6.5.1

Comment: have you solved this issue? sees the code is correct, maybe you need to choose you frame I don't know. also there is status bar in iOS 7 that is the part of the view now. Please check the admob view size. Also it is bad practice to have calculation in the CGRectMake method, if you separate this sometimes it can save a lot of your time.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine for me on iOS 7,

```
bannerView_      = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];   
bannerView_.adUnitID           = @"your-mediation-id";
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0,518,320,50);
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Why are you setting a delegate?

Comment: why not? the delegate it is right solution to process callback.